# How to verify that huge result of Solve?

Tags: equation-solving

Answering a question at [MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4540543/a-system-with-finitely-many-solutions/4541032#4541032),

I solve (in 13.1 on Windows 10)

```
Solve[{a x + b y + z == u, a x^2 + b y^2 + z^2 == v, a x^3 + b y^3 + z^3 == w}, 
{x, y, z},  Assumptions -> a != 0 && b != 0 && a + 1 != 0 && b + 1 != 0 && a + b != 0 && a + b + 1 != 0]
```

This produces the solution where `x,y,z` are expressed as roots of polynomials with coefficients from the field of rational functions $\mathbb Q (a,b,u,v,w)$.
The whole output takes 79.6 MB in memory. [Here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/bmnbxpjy4fqtt33/%D0%97%D0%BD%D1%96%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BA%20%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B0%202022-09-28%2019.23.53.png?dl=0)
is the screen of the shortened output. BTW, the execution of the command is not long.

The question arises: how to verify that huge output? The point is that the outputs of

```
 a = 1; b = -1; Solve[{a x + b y + z == u, a x^2 + b y^2 + z^2 == v, 
  a x^3 + b y^3 + z^3 == w}, {x, y, z}]
```

> `{{x -> (4 u^3 - 4 w -   Sqrt[(-4 u^3 + 4 w)^2 - 4 (6 u^2 - 6 v) (u^4 + 3 v^2 - 4 u w)])/( 12 (u^2 - v)), y -> (-u^3 + 3 u v - 2 w)/(3 (u^2 - v)),  z -> (-2 u^3 + u^5/(u^2 - v) - (u^3 v)/(u^2 - v) + 2 w - (u^2 w)/( u^2 - v) + (v w)/(u^2 - v) - ( u^2 Sqrt[(-4 u^3 + 4 w)^2 -  4 (6 u^2 - 6 v) (u^4 + 3 v^2 - 4 u w)])/(4 (u^2 - v)) +  Sqrt[(-4 u^3 + 4 w)^2 -   4 (6 u^2 - 6 v) (u^4 + 3 v^2 - 4 u w)])/ (4 (u^2 - v)))/(-3 u^2 + 3 v)}, {x -> (   4 u^3 - 4 w + Sqrt[(-4 u^3 + 4 w)^2 - 4 (6 u^2 - 6 v) (u^4 + 3 v^2 - 4 u w)])/ (12 (u^2 - v)), y -> (-u^3 + 3 u v - 2 w)/(3 (u^2 - v)),  z -> (-2 u^3 + u^5/(u^2 - v) - (u^3 v)/(u^2 - v) + 2 w - (u^2 w)/ (u^2 - v) + (v w)/(u^2 - v) + (u^2 Sqrt[(-4 u^3 + 4 w)^2 -  4 (6 u^2 - 6 v) (u^4 + 3 v^2 - 4 u w)])/(4 (u^2 - v)) - (v Sqrt[(-4 u^3 + 4 w)^2 -  4 (6 u^2 - 6 v) (u^4 + 3 v^2 - 4 u w)])/   (4 (u^2 - v)))/(-3 u^2 + 3 v)}}`

(without any warnings)  and

```
 a = 1; b = -1; Reduce[{a x + b y + z == u, a x^2 + b y^2 + z^2 == v, 
  a x^3 + b y^3 + z^3 == w}, {x, y, z}]
```

> `(u^2 - v !=  0 && (x == ( 4 u^3 - 4 w - Sqrt[(-4 u^3 + 4 w)^2 - 4 (6 u^2 - 6 v) (u^4 + 3 v^2 - 4 u w)])/(12 (u^2 - v)) ||  x == (4 u^3 - 4 w +  Sqrt[(-4 u^3 + 4 w)^2 - 4 (6 u^2 - 6 v) (u^4 + 3 v^2 - 4 u w)])/(12 (u^2 - v))) &&  y == (-u^3 + 3 u v - 2 w)/(3 (u^2 - v)) &&   z == u - x + y) || (w == 0 && v == 0 && u == 0 && x == 0 &&  z == y) || ((v == w^(2/3) || v == -(-1)^(1/3) w^(2/3) ||  v == (-1)^(2/3) w^(2/3)) && v != 0 && u == w/v && x == u &&  z == y) || (w == 0 && v == 0 && u == 0 && -x != 0 && y == x &&  z == -x + y) || ((v == w^(2/3) || v == -(-1)^(1/3) w^(2/3) ||  v == (-1)^(2/3) w^(2/3)) && v != 0 && u == w/v && u - x != 0 &&  y == x && z == u - x + y)`

essentially differ in  `&&   z == u - x + y) || (w == 0 && v == 0 && u == 0 && x == 0 &&  z == y) || ((v == w^(2/3) || v == -(-1)^(1/3) w^(2/3) ||  v == (-1)^(2/3) w^(2/3)) && v != 0 && u == w/v && x == u &&  z == y) || (w == 0 && v == 0 && u == 0 && -x != 0 && y == x &&  z == -x + y) || ((v == w^(2/3) || v == -(-1)^(1/3) w^(2/3) ||  v == (-1)^(2/3) w^(2/3)) && v != 0 && u == w/v && u - x != 0 &&  y == x && z == u - x + y)` so the result of `Solve` cannot be treated as reliable.

---

.

Comment: PS. The command `Reduce[{a x + b y + z == u, a x^2 + b y^2 + z^2 == v, a x^3 + b y^3 + z^3 == w}, {x, y, z}]` is running without any response for hours.

Comment: `{ a->1,b->-1}` don't fullfill your assumptions: `a != 0 && b != 0 && a + 1 != 0 && b + 1 != 0 && a + b != 0 && 
  a + b + 1 != 0 /. {a -> 1, b -> -1} ` evaluates to `False`

Comment: @UlrichNeumann: Thank you for your interest to the question. You open an opened door. I give that  as an example of a related problem where  `Solve` produces a non-complete output without any warning. Compare with the result of `Solve[RealAbs[x + y] + RealAbs[x + y + 1] == 1, {x, y}, Reals]`.

Comment: In Maple 2018 the result of `solve({a*x+b*y+z = u, a*x^2+b*y^2+z^2 = v, a*x^3+b*y^3+z^3 = w}, {x, y, z}) assuming a <> 0, b <> 0, a+1 <> 0, b+1 <> 0, a+b <> 0, a+b+1 <> 0;` is not so big , but for `allvalues(%)`  the  length of its output exceeds limit of 1000000.

Comment: If I understood, you want the conditions for the solution from Solve to be valid. Assuming, {x,y,z} are real valued and taking `s=Solve[{a x + b y + z == u, a x^2 + b y^2 + z^2 == v, 
   a x^3 + b y^3 + z^3 == w}, {x, y, z}]`  why not check the conditions that determine when the solutions from Solve are real ? For example, considering the first solution `DeleteCases[Reduce[s[[1]] /. Rule -> Equal, {x, y, z}, Reals], 
 x == _ | y == _ | z == _, Infinity]`

Comment: @userrandrand: Thank you for your interest to the question. You wrote "If I understood, you want the conditions for the solution from Solve to be valid". No, I  am not interested in any conditions. The question is: how to verify the huge result of `Solve`? BTW, real algebraic geometry is  harder than the one over complexes.

Comment: But if you want to verify Solve regardless of whether the variables are complex you could do sol=Solve[...] then equations /. sol[[1]] for example. Also yes in general working with complex variables is easier in particular because they have less constraints (for variables to be real)

Comment: You are very correct that "so the result of Solve cannot be treated as reliable". Especially when huge output is generated. Verification is not possible in such a case.